# Cache class objects

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, caching

My project is WPF application.

I have a class for example `Products` having multiple properties(`string` , `int`, `List<>`). I am looking to cache this object in memory (not in file), and use it. 
Also looking for event raised when cache object is updated similarly as `HostFileChangeMonitor`.

The reason why I am looking for above solution is: 
I have to send current object to third party dll (which is on timer of 5 sec) and it is heavy object which hampering performance of GUI.
Hence by caching class object, I will monitor to call this heavy operation ONLY WHEN cache object is updated.

I already thought to save object properties value to txt file and use `HostFileChangeMonitor` to trigger event, but this will add one more IO operation.

Please share if any inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all to view my question. Finally I got working code with time specific memory cache. 
Posting it may be it is useful for someone like me. It is explained with an example.

```
    private MemoryCache mc = new MemoryCache("CacheProvider"); // Creating memory cache object.

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Method to get cache elements.
    private void GetCache_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lstEmployeeID.Items.Clear();
        lstEmployeeName.Items.Clear();
        var emp = new Employee();
        foreach (Employee emp1 in emp.GetEmployeeList())
        {
            var cacheObj = mc[emp1.EmployeeName] as Employee; // typecasting it class object.
            if (cacheObj != null)
            {
                lstEmployeeID.Items.Add(cacheObj.EmployeeId);
                lstEmployeeName.Items.Add(cacheObj.EmployeeName);
            }
        }

    }

    // Saving class object to cache.
    private void SaveCache_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         var emp = new Employee();
        var policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
        policy.AbsoluteExpiration = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(10.0);
        foreach (Employee emp1 in emp.GetEmployeeList())
        {
            mc.Add(emp1.EmployeeName, emp1, policy); // adding (key, objectItem, CachingPolicy)
        }
    }
```